# How to get last inserted records(row) in all tables in Firebird database?

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I have a problem. I need to get last inserted rows in all tables in Firebird db. And one more, these rows must contain specfied column name. I read some articles about rdb$ but have a few experience with that one.

Comment: Why do you need the last record? Perhaps there is easier / better way to solve the problem...

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way to get "last row inserted" unless the table has a timestamp field which stores that information (insertion timestamp).

If the table uses integer PK generated by sequense (generator in Firebird lingo) then you could query for the higest PK value but this isn't reliable either.

Comment: Not every table in my db use integer primary key. I can get all tables names (names list) via rdb$. I dont know how to construct query for each of these name to find max(id).

Comment: it is impossible to find last inserted rows without surrogate id autoincrement field, nor you are using triggers to log inserts

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of 'last row inserted'. Visibility and availability to other transactions depends on the time of commit, transaction isolation specified etc. Even use of a generator or timestamp as suggested by ain does not really help because of this visibility issue.

Maybe you are better of specifying the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'll try to explain my problem. I have table in db (id, someval, someval2, etc.). Also I have a generator for autoincrement id field. When I'm inserting new record without predefined id (works GEN_ID()) everything works fine. When I insert record with optional(random) id (e.g export some data) it works too, but when i try to insert next record after this - i receive error with access violation. Thats why I need to control id values from generator and from the last insertion. Maybe i need to make some fixes in my autoincrement method?

Comment: I assume you mean an unique/primary key constraint violation instead of an access violation otherwise it would be a bug. In any case: make sure there is only one way: always using the generator value. If you need that value, look into [INSERT ... RETURNING](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-insert.html#langrefupd25-insert-returning)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GEN_ID(ID_HEDER,0)+1 FROM ANY_TABLE INTO :ID;
INSERT INTO INVOICE_HEADER (No,Date_of,Etc) VALUES ('122','2013-10-20','Any text')
/* ID record of INVOICE_HEADER table gets the ID_number from the generator above. So 
   now we have to check if the ID =GEN_ID(ID_HEADER,0) */
IF (ID=GEN_ID(ID_HEADER,0)) THEN 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INVOICE_FOOTER (RELACION_ID, TEXT, Etc) Values (ID, 'Text', Etc);
END
ELSE
    REVERT TRANSACTION
```

That is all